# Asynchronous calls not working properly ajax asmx webservice?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, web-services, asp.net-ajax

I have a strange issue with asp.net webforms, I solved it, but I don't like the way I solved it so I'm looking for other options.

I have a method in a webservice(.asmx) and I'm calling it using jquery ajax ($.ajax), it works fine when I DON'T USE BREAKPOINTS, but if I USE A BREAKPOINT the callback will return with error even if I haven't stopped debugging the method.

Let me try to explain it better:

Scenario 1 - I execute the method without debugging. (async: true)
Scenario 1 result = It works fine.

Scenario 2 - I execute the method debbuging.  (async: true)
Scenario 2 result = IT GOES BACK TO JQUERY BEFORE I FINISH DEBUGGING THE METHOD AND the error status is just 'error' no important information about it.

Scenario 3 - I execute the method without debugging. (async: false)
Scenario 3 result = It works fine.

Scenario 4 - I execute the method without debugging. (async: false)
Scenario 4 result = It works fine.

Client side:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WBSJsonRequests.asmx/InsertInterConsulta",
        data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (JsonResponseData) {

            if (JsonResponseData.d === "success") {
                alert("Se han agregado la esta especialidad correctamente!");
            }
            else {
                alert("Se ha producido un error en el servidor: " + JsonResponseData.d);
            }
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            console.log(textStatus);

            alert(textStatus);
        }

    });
```

Server side:

```
<WebMethod(Description:="Inserta Interconsulta")>
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json)>
Public Function InsertInterConsulta(InterConsultaList As InterConsulta, IdCita As Integer) As String
    Dim Searializer As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Try
        InterConsultaList.IdCita = IdCita
        Meds.InterConsulta.GuardarInterConsulta(InterConsultaList.IdEspecialidad, InterConsultaList.IdCita)
        Return "success"
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
End Function
```

End Function

Comment: There must be *some* information.  What is actually throwing the error?  What is the actual response (response code, content, applicable headers, etc.) coming back from the server to the AJAX call?

Comment: I said " the error status is just 'error' no important information about it.", errorThrown variable is blank, textStatus just says "error" and xmlhttprequest is blank. and the response status is 200 ok

Comment: WHY DID I GET A BAD SCOREEE?????, I DIDN'T DO ANYTHING WRONG...

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find out what was happening, the thing is that if you have asyn: true, and you're making an ajax request through an event, you need to do an "e.preventDefault()", before doing the request, or it'll do it over and over.